# How I will use the one of the output column name in same SQL statement for sum calculation

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

```
select 
    nodw as "node ID",
    riskvale as "TotalRis",
    (portvalue - marvalue) as "TotalMarValue" 
    --{ Here I want to take the upper column value i.e ""TotalRis"" / "TotalMarValue" * 100 } as "total Uses"**
from 
    abc
```

I want to use the output of "TotalRis" and "TotalMarValue" column to get the output for other column. I tried with @{TotalRis} but query not getting execute.

Comment: what do you mean by `upper column value `? please provide sample data / desired output

Comment: I mean that I want to use the output from "TotalRis" and "TotalMarValue" columns to get the output for other column. So 

"TotalRis"" / "TotalMarValue" * 100 as "Total Uses"

Comment: then use them. what's the problem

Comment: I tried like this but getting error message 

"select nodw as "node ID",
riskvale as "TotalRis",
(portvalue - marvalue) as "TotalMarValue"
( "TotalRis" / "TotalMarValue" ) * 100 as "Total Uses"
from abc"

SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "TotalRis" does not exist
  Position: 150

Answer (score 0):

you can't use alias , as they are the last part of the query that query engine will parse, so :

```
select 
    nodw as "node ID",
    riskvale as "TotalRis",
    (portvalue - marvalue) as "TotalMarValue", 
    riskvale / (portvalue - marvalue) * 100  as "total Uses"
from abc
```